# Modifying Dataframes Stored in a List of Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am segmenting data into a set of Pandas dataframes that have identical structure.  For each dataframe, there are a total of *cnames* columns that have unique names, and a total of *nrows* rows, that are identified by an integer-valued index running from 0 to *nrows*-1.  There are a total of *nframes* segments, each containing 3 dataframes.

The goal is, within each segment, calculate a quotient of two of the dataframes and send the result to the third.  I've implemented and tested a process that works, but have a question as to why a slight variation of the process doesn't.

The steps (and variation) are as follows:

1. Initialize data frames:

```
Ldf_num = [pd.DataFrame(0.0, index=range(0, nrows), columns=cnames) for x in range(0, nframes)]
Ldf_den = [pd.DataFrame(0.0, index=range(0, nrows), columns=cnames) for x in range(0, nframes)]
Ldf_quo = [pd.DataFrame(0.0, index=range(0, nrows), columns=cnames) for x in range(0, nframes)]
```

2. Populate data frames:

```
#For loop over a set of data-records stored as a list of lists:
    
    #Determine x, the index of the data frame related to this record, from the data
    df_num = Ldf_num[x]
    df_den = Ldf_den[x]

    #Derive values (including row) for each column of the data frame, and store them as...
    df_num[cname][row] += derived_value1
    df_den[cname][row] += derived_value2
```

3. Determine quotient for each set of dataframes:

```
for x in range(0, nframes):
    df_num = Ldf_num[x]
    df_den = Ldf_den[x]

    Ldf_quo[x] = df_num.div(df_den)
```

The above version of step 3 worked, i.e. I can print each dataframe in the quotient dataframe, and see that they have different values that match the numerator and denominator values.

3b.  However, the versison below did not work:

```
for x in range(0, nframes):
    df_num = Ldf_num[x]
    df_den = Ldf_den[x]
    df_quo = Ldf_quo[x]

    df_quo = df_num.div(df_den)
```

...as all entries in all dataframes in the list Ldf_quo contained their initial value of 0.

Can anyone explain why when I assign a variable to a single dataframe stored in a list of dataframes, and I change values of the assigned variable, it changes the values in the original dataframe in the list in step 2...

...but when I send the output of the "div" method to a variable assigned to a single dataframe in a list of dataframes as in step 3b, the values in the original dataframe do not change (but I can get the desired result by sending the output from the "div" method explicitly to the right slot in the list of dataframes, as in step 3)

Answer (score 0):

In the answer 3b. you are assigning the value at Ldf_quo[x] to df_quo which basically be an integer. However, when you do Ldf_quo[x], you assigning df_num.div(df_den) at the xth index of the data frame.